# Should I switch majors? How will this look on grad school application?

Tags: graduate-school, academic-life, science, major

At the school I study at there are several majors for life sciences. I am currently in a program called Life science - origin of diseases specialization. This program is very similar to the general life science program but has several more requirements for this degree. I still have a few more to finish but I realized that these courses are hard and a waste of my time. Most of these courses that I have to do are Organic chemistry 1 & 2, cell biology, etc. Which as most science students would know are **difficult and time-consuming.** After realizing that I don't plan on going to professional school (med, dentistry, and pharm) and just want to go straight to masters or a diploma, these courses mean nothing to me.

So my question is, it better to switch the general life science major that doesn't require these courses. Doing so would let me have more free time to find research and volunteer opportunities and hopefully keep my GPA up. Or would it be better to just stay in this program and finish it since I'm already halfway there (I am going on to my third year of studies)? But doing so would give me less free time and potentially deflate my GPA as these courses are known to crush your GPA. The two correlate a lot so I won't be missing any prerequisites for the degree when I do make the switch.

Thanks for taking your time to read this :)

Comment: Masters in what? Anything life sciences related probably wants to see organic chemistry at the least.

Comment: What do you want to do when you're done with school? Is the "general life science" degree going to qualify you for that?

Comment: @JonCuster unfortunately I do not know and am having difficulties finding out what I want to do. However, lots of the programs I have looked at don't require these courses and prefer experiences more.